# Change culture in controller ASP.Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've searched around and haven't been able to find an answer that worked for me.

My question is: **how to set the culture of the current response within a controller method.**

The scenario is as follows. We have a general area of the web application, which works with culture set via a cookie, which works fine.

One small part of the website, though, needs to be in Danish always, except if a query parameter is set to, for instance, en-GB.

In the controller method receiving the request I add the culture change to the cookie, but the returned view is still displayed in the previous language. A refresh of the page will then display the view in the correct language, since the cookie now has the correct values.

What I would like is to also change the culture of the current request besides the cookie, so that the returned view is displayed in the correct language.

My controller's code is as follows:

```
    [Route("{organizationId}/{arrangementId}")]
    public IActionResult LandingPage(int organizationId, int arrangementId, [FromQuery] string lang, [FromQuery] bool? allowup)
    {
        if (organizationId <= 0 || arrangementId <= 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        _utils.SetLoginRedirectUrl($"/Skolevaccination/Questionnaire/{organizationId}/{arrangementId}", Response);

        SetLanguage(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lang) ? lang : "da-DK");


        ViewBag.allowup = allowup ?? false;

        return View("Index");
    }

    private void SetLanguage(string lang)
    {
        string cultureCookieValue;
        switch (lang)
        {
            case "gb":
            case "en-GB":
                cultureCookieValue = CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture("en-GB"));
                _cultureService.SetCulture(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                break;
            case "dk":
            case "da-DK":
                cultureCookieValue = CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture("da-DK"));
                _cultureService.SetCulture(new CultureInfo("da-DK"));
                break;
            default:
                _logger.LogInformation($"Trying to set a language {lang}, which isn't supported.");
                return;
        }
        Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName, cultureCookieValue);
    }
```

The call to _cultureService.SetCulture(new CultureInfo("da-DK")) uses the following code, which are my attempts at solving the problem:

```
    public void SetCulture(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (!GetSupportedCultures().Contains(cultureInfo))
        {
            throw new CultureNotFoundException("The given culture is not supported.");
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

        //CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        //CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    }
```

As seen I tried setting the thread's current culture and using the static methods on CultureInfo as well (the commented out lines).

A lot of the posts I found online mentioned that setting the thread's culture was a thing used previous to ASP.Net 5 (ASP.Net core) and that all culture settings are now set up in the startup file. But if I change it in the startup file, I change it for the whole website, which is not what we want. And I need to set the cookie as well, since subsequent pages on the small part of the whole website needs to use the language set via the URL or the default one, but their urls will not have the language defined there.

If this can't be solved by setting the current culture directly, could it perhaps be solved by setting up a routing area for this specific part of the web app?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT 2018/10/05**

I found a solution after looking closer at the view and its IViewLocalizer.

After looking closer at the documentation for the localizer classes I found that you can use their method `WithCulture`. This returns a new localizer for the same strings but for the given culture.

But after still having troubles with the view not being localized correctly, I found that the injected localizer in the view isn't the same as the one injected in the controller, so to fully localize the request, the localizer in both the controller and the view needs to be exchanged using the `WithCulture` method.

My solution ended up like the following:

In the controller:

```
    private void SetLanguage(string lang, string defaultLang)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lang) || !_cultureService.IsSupportedCulture(lang)) {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Tried to change culture to unsupported culture (to {lang}). Culture has been set to default culture {defaultLang}.");
            lang = defaultLang;
        }

        string cultureCookieValue;
        switch (lang)
        {
            case "gb":
            case "en-GB":
                cultureCookieValue = CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture("en-GB"));
                _localizer = _localizer.WithCulture(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                ViewBag.changeCulture = true;
                ViewBag.lang = "en-GB";
                break;
            case "dk":
            case "da-DK":
                cultureCookieValue = CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture("da-DK"));
                _localizer = _localizer.WithCulture(new CultureInfo("da-DK"));
                ViewBag.changeCulture = true;
                ViewBag.lang = "da-DK";
                break;
            default:
                _logger.LogInformation($"Trying to set a language {lang}, which isn't supported.");
                return;
        }
        Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName, cultureCookieValue);
    }
```

When calling this method in the controller, I set some data in the view bag, which is used in the view to also create a new localizer there:

```
@inject IViewLocalizer ViewLocalizer

@{
    IHtmlLocalizer Localizer = ViewLocalizer;
    if (ViewBag.changeCulture) {
        var lang = ViewBag.lang;
        Localizer = Localizer.WithCulture(new CultureInfo(lang));
    }
    var allowUserPasswordLogin = ViewBag.allowup;
}
```

When calling the `WithCulture` method the returned type is IHtmlLocalizer, which can't be cast back to a IViewLocalizer, but IViewLocalizer extends the IHtmlLocalizer interface, so it all works out with a few lines of code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: What about [Content-Language](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.12) header?

Comment: After clearing my head and looking closer at the view and its injected localizer, I found a solution. I'm adding it to the main post.

Comment: Rather than editing the question, ideally you should add your solution as an answer.

Comment: I'll remember that for next time, thanks for the advice!